# AppleScript return on random float

Tags: random, numbers, click, applescript

I'm trying to create code in AppleScript that will click my mouse randomly every 1-2 seconds... I want a video game I'm playing to not know or be able to tell that a robot is clicking for me so I need it to be RANDOM... not every second or every 2 seconds but every x seconds where x is a constantly changing variable in-between 1 and 2 seconds... Here is the code so far but it clicks every 1 second:

```
on idle
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 87
    end tell
    return 1
end idle
```

I thought changing the `return 1` to `return random number 1 to 2` would work

Something like this:

```
on idle
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 87
    end tell
    set randomDelay to random number from 1 to 2
    return randomDelay
end idle
```

but it didn't work /:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it into

```
random number from 1.0 to 2.0
```

If you give integers as the bounds for the random numbers, it will just select random integers. By giving floating point literals, AppleScript switches to giving a random floating point number in the range. From the documentation of `random number` in the StandardAdditions, it seems that the limits are both inclusive, which is strange for floats but isn't a problem in your case.