# Need to randomize time for a AppleScript Autoclicker

Tags: macos, random, click, applescript, delay

As you can read from the title, I need to randomize the time between my auto clicker clicks.

My auto clicker uses AppleScript programming language. It is very basic, but I need it to be random and not constant.

What I have so far is:

```
on idle
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 12
    end tell
    return 0.5
end idle
```

I know, this would press q rather than click, but that's beside my question and I want it that way. What I really need to do is code my Mac auto clicker to be 115-170 milliseconds.

Thanks to anyone who responds!

Comment: This is AppleScript, not Swift

Comment: @A248 Ahhh, I remember auto-clicking in RuneScape :3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AppleScript return on random float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057289/applescript-return-on-random-float)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
return (random number from 0.115 to 0.17)
```